# Recoger datos pathname y mostralos en la vista en React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, parametros

Estoy tratando de recoger el pathname de mi url y no encuentro la manera. Intento recoger los parametros de la ruta dinamica de id y me encuentro con multiples errores.
Alguien puede echarme una mano, por favor.
Gracias

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import Peliculas from '../Peliculas/Peliculas';
import Error from '../Error/Error';

const Router = () => {
      
      return (

        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path='/' element = {<Peliculas/>}/>   
            <Route path='*' element = {<Error/>}/>
            <Route exact path='/:id' element= { (props) => {
                const id = props.match.params.id;
                <div id='content'>
                  <h1 className='subheader'>Hola amigo</h1>
                  <h2>{id}</h2>
                </div>              
            }       
            }/>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Router;
```

Answer (score 1):

De la forma en que lo hago yo es usando `useParams` de React route.

de la siguiente forma:

```
//En la vista usando Link de react route enviamos el id
import {Link}  from "react-router-dom"
.....
<Link to={`../Aviso/idAviso=${a.id}`} className="btn btn-primary">Más informacion</Link>
```

En el enrutador:

```
<Routes>
//Retornamos eel componente aviso
<Route path="/Aviso/idAviso=:id" element={<Aviso/>} />
</Routes>
```

Y en el componente:

```
export default function Aviso(){
    const {id} = useParams()
    console.log(id)
}
```

De esta forma puedes obtener el `id` con react route, sin embargo veo que lo quieres obtener dentro del mismo "enrutador", por lo tanto talvez te sirva el ejemplo que muestra React Route dentro de su documentacion:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function ProfilePage() {
  // Get the userId param from the URL.
  let { userId } = useParams();
  // ...
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="users">
        <Route path=":userId" element={<ProfilePage />} />
        <Route path="me" element={...} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

[En este enlace](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) puedes obtener mas informacion, es la documentacion oficila de React Route.

Comment: Hola David, gracias por responder. Si que me gustaria hacerlo dentro del enroutador, ya utilice el useParams, pero tampoco consegui de ninguna manera pintar el {id}. Tambien utilicé el código que ofrece la documentación oficial y no me funcionaba. La verdad es que probe muchas cosas y no logré encontrar donde esta el error.

Comment: David081, [fijate](/review/suggested-edits/354600) por qué se rechazó tu edición a la pregunta.